# Cantors diagonal argument

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Statement**: The natural numbers are not equinumerous to the real numbers

**Proof**: Suppose $f:\omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $(1-1)$. We show that ran$(f)\neq\mathbb{R}$ so such an $f$ can never be a bijection.

We assume that the real numbers in ran$(f)$ are written out in decimal notation.

$f(0)=3.1415926...$

$f(1)=-2.4245...$

$f(2)=176.011$

We let $x$ be the number $0.212...$ obtained by letting $x$ have $0$ integer part, and putting at the $n+1$'st decimal place a $1$ if the $n+1$st decimal place of $f(n)$ is even and a $2$ if it is odd.

The argument concludes by noting that $x$ cannot be $f(n)$ for any $n$ as it is deliberately made to differ from $f(n)$ at the $n+1$'st decimal place

**My understanding**: I feel that I need further clarification as to how this proof works, this is my understanding:

We construct a number $x$ from a series of random numbers $f(n)$

From $f(0)$, we have the first decimal place of $f(0)$ is $1$ giving $x$, $n+1=1$st decimal place value $2$ so we have so far: $x=0.2$

From $f(1)$, we have the second decimal place of $f(1)$ is $2$ giving $x$, $n+1=2$nd decimal place value $1$ so we have now: $x=0.21$

From $f(2)$, we have the third decimal place of $f(2)$ is $1$ giving $x$, $n+1=3$rd decimal place value $2$ so we have now: $x=0.212$

And so on...

Is this the correct interpretation of how to construct $x$ in the proof? Also are all $f(n)$ random?

Comment: How do you define $ran(f)$? I never heard of that in terms of functions.

Comment: @Lukas $\operatorname{ran}f$ is defined the set of all values which is taken by $f(x)$; i.e. $\operatorname{ran}f=\{f(x):x\in A\}$ where $A$ is the domain of $f$.

Comment: @Lukas: It's a relatively less common notation for the range of $f$, or the image of $f$.

Comment: Ah, never saw that one before… Always knew it to be the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't construct "random numbers". You are given the function $f$ (you don't need it to be injective, by the way), and from each $f(n)$ which is a real number you define a decimal digit which will be the $n$-th digit of $x$.

By choosing these digits wisely you can have that $x\neq f(n)$ for every $n$, therefore $x\notin\operatorname{ran}(f)$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but for example for $f(5)$ does the $5$th decimal place have to be even, what number could you construct for $f(5)$ as an example?

Comment: If $f(5)$ is such that the fifth decimal digit is even, then taking the fifth decimal digit of $x$ to be $7$ ensures that $x\neq f(5)$.

Comment: How is the fifth decimal digit of $f(5)$ determined? Also $x$ was constructed to only have decimal values of $1$ and $2$, so can I pick either if the fifth decimal digit is $7$?

Comment: You define the algorithm for choosing the digit, if you only allow $0,1$ then pick $1$ instead of $7$. The point is that it doesn't matter. You just have to remember to choose wisely.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, so as long as the value picked for $x$ at that decimal place is not the value at that decimal place for $f(n)$, then it is ok, e.g. I can pick $x$ to have value $2$ at decimal point $n$ if $f(n)$ has value $4$ say.

Comment: Yes, you can pick any of the $9$ digits, which are different.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, you just have to remember to avoid $0$ and $9$ too much, or else you'll choose for $0.499999\ldots$ the number $0.50000\ldots$ which are essential equal. But if you stay clear of those issues, then it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The main argument that sustains the proof is the unicity of the decimal representation of each real numbers (not true for decimal numbers but not relevant here). Without this you cannot conclude, and it also explains why Cantor thought of this proof.

So you want to prove that [0,1] is not equinumerous to N. Let's consider any subset of [0,1] equinumerous to N, which I will denote with the sequence: $r=(r_1,r_2,...)$, and let's prove that one can always construct an element x of [0,1] that is not in this subset.

You will now use what you described in your question. Given the n-th term of r (ie $r_n$), I choose to set the n-th decimal of x as such:

if the n-th decimal of $r_n$ is different from 1 then the n-th decimal of x is set to 1, else it is set to 2.

Now, by construction, you can see that the decimals of x always differ at least by one term from the decimals of any term of the sequence r (the n-th decimal of x is different of the n-th decimal of $r_n$). That is precisely why you change the value. And you know that x has an infinite decimal representation, so by unicity you can conclude that x is never equal to any of the $r_i$, hence you have built a new element that is not in your subset r, yet equinumerous to N.

You can then conclude that [0,1] is not equinumerous to N.

So you understood the construction, but random f(n) is not relevant here. All you need to understand is that proving that [0,1] is not equinumerous to N is the same as building a new element, given any subset r equinumerous to N, that is not in r.